# C++: Overloading operators for similar integer types

Tags: c++, g++, operator-overloading

I have a type called `MyType` that is an `int`:

```
typedef int MyType;
```

It gets treated as an `int` throughout the code.

I'd like to be able to overload an operator separately for both `int` and `MyType`:

```
class C
{
public:
   C& operator>>(int i) {}
   C& operator>>(MyType i) {}
};
```

but I can't:

```
overload.cpp:7:7: error: 'C& C::operator>>(MyType)' cannot be overloaded
overload.cpp:6:7: error: with 'C& C::operator>>(int)'
```

Can I have my cake and eat it too?

Comment: you don't have a cake. you have an alias for int. If you want a separate type, there is a boost package for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per usual, you need a strong typedef. One implementation of that is [`BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html).

Answer (score 4):

As @Cat++ said, BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF is a good solution. However for those who don't want to rely on boost library (no mistake if you do) it is easier to do it this way:

```
#define TYPEDEF(original_type,target_type)struct target_type{\
    original_type value;\
    explicit target_type(const original_type val):value(val){}\
    target_type(){}\
    target_type(const target_type& other):value(other.value){}\
    target_type& operator=(const original_type& rhs){value = rhs; return *this;}\
    target_type& operator=(const target_type& rhs){value = rhs.value; return *this;}\
    bool operator==(const target_type& rhs){return value == rhs.value;}\
    bool operator<(const target_type& rhs){return value < rhs.value;}\
    operator const original_type&() const{return value;}\
    operator original_type&(){return value;}\
}
```

Usage: `TYPEDEF(int, MyType);`

**So What Does this Macro Do?**
This macro basically creates a new structure that can easily be treated as the original type in many ways. And to the compiler this is a totally different type.

Take your `MyType` for instance. When you declare it as `typedef int MyType;`, at compile time, `MyType` gets replaced by `int`. And since you already have a function defined with `int` as the parameter, it would complain about duplicate function body.

When you do `TYPEDEF(int, MyType);`, MyType is a structure that can be initialized and assigned a value of int type and would be treated by the compiler as a totally different data-type from int. Yet you will be able to assign it `int` values because of the `operator =` function and retrieve its value as an `int` because of its `operator const original_type&() const` and `operator original_type&()` functions.

This roughly what boost does with its `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` macro but it seems to be inheriting from other internal classes and I'm not sure what those classes does. But this is a crude solution for those who don't want to rely on boost for whatever reason.

**My Personal Recommendation**: Use boost whenever possible.